# Combine results of multiple ajax-requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

in my webapp there are two types of entities, which are in relation to each other.
At first i grab some entities of type a and then for every single one of them, i grab the related ones of type b as an array. All working.
When all requests are done, i need an array of all returned type-b-arrays. Not working!
Whats the best way to accomplish that in jquery ?

Comment: Can you give us the code you are working with that does this? Thanks

Comment: Without seeing some code, we can only offer very general suggestions.

Comment: What's not working? What have you tried? What does the code currently look like?

Comment: Thx all, it was more of a general Question, antonlavey got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some others have commented here will need some code samples to get a bit more specific but a thought off the top of my head:

You could construct a global array of arrays that you feed you "type b" arrays into as they are returned from the ajax call.  Would look something like this:

```
//Define this outside your function scope
var typeBArrays = new Array();

function someAjaxCallback(typeBArray){
    typeBArrays[typeBArrays.length] = typeBArray;
}
```

So when your processing is done you can access the typeBArrays array and have all your returned arrays.

Comment: Yeah, had a same solution, but with a typo, so it didnt work. i thought javascript couldnt handle the writing from different subfunctions, but you showed me,THX